# What's the per phase equivalent circuit of induction motor with asymmetric windings?

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-measurement, induction-motor, electric-machine

We know that there's T equivalent circuit and inverse Γ-equivalent circuit for 3 phase induction motor(IM). When the IM is operating under normal situation, the windings are symmetrical, so all 3 phases equivalent circuit should be the same, but when a fault occur to it—e.g., inter turn short circuit(ITSC) of phase A, the windings become asymmetrical. Is it okay to use equivalent circuit to reprensent each winding? Which means, same structure of equivalent circuit while the value of the parameters are different.
I looked up some information about this: when the motor is fault free, the windings are symmetrical, and the input supply voltage equals to phase to neutral voltage, but when the fualt happens, the neutral point shifts, input supply voltage can't stand for phase to neutral voltage.
However, I'm still confused. Anyone knowing this to elaborate more about this? How to measure the right input voltage and is there a way to simulate it in matlab?